# DBScan function - how get all plots of iteration

Tags: r, dbscan

By using function dbscan as below:

```
ds <- dbscan(x, 0.2,showplot=1)
```

We can see plots of sets in every iteration. Unfortunately, there is a lot of plots, so in R-Studio I have only the 30 last. How can I get all plots?

If i do:

```
jpeg("dbscans.jpeg")
ds <- dbscan(x, 0.2,showplot=1)
dev.off()
```

It of course doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because you are outputting to a jpeg. This works for me:

```
library(fpc)
pdf("dbscan.pdf")
ds <- dbscan(mtcars[,c(1,2)],2,showplot=T)
dev.off()
```

BTW: you don't need to assign `dbscan(...)` to anything. This works as well:

```
library(fpc)
pdf("dbscan.pdf")
dbscan(mtcars[,c(1,2)],2,showplot=T)
dev.off()
```